# Can ESP8266 Wi-Fi module Send pictures without adding additional RAM?

Tags: image-processing, wifi, ram, wireless, esp8266

I am planning to send pictures from SD card via ESP8266 Wi-Fi Module to either webpage or android device. However, I don't know if the MCU inside ESP8266 can process large data like pictures without adding external RAM?

Answer (score 0):

How many bytes do you want to send from the ESP8266 ??

I came across http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2852 wherein the user is sending an image of 320*240 pix i.e. 153738 bytes, but sending 2048 bytes at a time.

It all boils down to:-

1) How many images do you want to send ?

2) What is the size for your each image ?

3) Is there a time constraint to sending image ?

Answer (score -1):

You do not need extra memory, you just have to upload the photo files by stream. [Here's](https://github.com/mkazimoto/esp8266_sending_photo_to_telegram) an example.